# Go up/down the other end

Tags: word-meaning

What does "go up/down the other end" mean? I interpret it as "go up" as "go towards" and "the other end" as "the opponent pitch". "Other" means oppossing and "end" means the pitch. Whereas "down the left" means "on the left". Is my interpretation right?

> West Ham work it **down the left** and the cross comes in. It's initially headed away by Robinson, but Coufal hooks back over his own head into the danger zone, where Bowen has space to volley on his right foot, but it's too close to Leno.

> Fulham **go up the other end** and Cresswell blocks Iwobi's goal-bound volley behind...

Comment: Both teams are playing on **one** pitch; there is no such thing as 'the opponents' pitch'. "The other end" is the end opposite to the one where play is currently taking place.

Comment: @KateBunting Could you explain the use of *up* and *down* in a football context? *Down the field* means *on the field*? *Up the other end* means *towards the other end*?

Comment: I'm no football expert, but 'walking up the street' and 'walking down the street' can both mean simply 'walking along' (unless the street is on a hill). So I think both 'up' and 'down the pitch' just mean 'towards the other end'.

Comment: Totally agree with Kate. I would add that you could swap the up/down in both sentances and they would mean exactly the same as they do now, and not be unnatural.

Comment: @KateBunting So ***down*** the pitch means ***along*** the pitch, doesn't it?

Comment: @timchessish That makes sense. Your sentense uses "would" in *I **would** add that you could...*, I want to understand your use of "would", could you explain?

Comment: @Nyambek. "would" expresses conditionality, e.g. "if I would was a bird I would be able to fly". In this case there is an implied "If I had written that" before "I would".

Comment: @timchessish Thanks. Coud you substitute "would" for "will" in your sentence?  *I **will** add that you could...*.

Comment: @Nyambek. Yes. Strictly the meaning would be altered slightly, but in this context it makes no real difference. Maybe "would" acknowledges the previous contribution slightly more, which is why it feels better than "will".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150272/discussion-between-nyambek-and-timchessish).

Comment: Nyambek, there have been _many_  discussions on this forum about the use of 'would' - which is a different issue from your original question.

Comment: You should watch the game and give us a link. That's much easier.

Answer (score 0):

> West Ham work it down the left and the cross comes in.

Reading this, I imagine one or more West Ham players have managed to get the ball from the midfield toward the left wing fairly close to the opponent's goal line and then pass the ball in a cross to a position that would allow other players to kick or head the ball directly into the goal.

> Fulham go up the other end and Cresswell blocks Iwobi's goal-bound volley behind.

Reading this, I imagine that one or more Fulham players dribble and/or pass the ball from close to their own goal line across the midfield .  Iwobi then   volley's the ball at the goal after a pass in the air, but Cresswell blocks it.

**End**:

"The pitch" refers to the entire legal playing area.  Since a pitch is longer than it is wide, each half can be thought of as an end, as you divide the pitch into two halves or two ends.  The word "end" is somewhat vague, so you could also divide a pitch into three vague parts: two ends separated by the midfield.

**Left**:

You can also divide the width of the pitch into the left and right side, according to which goal is your reference point.  If you just say "the left," it is ambiguous whether you mean "the left wing" or "the left half," but usually the former is more useful and therefore more common, implying a position relatively close to the touchline/sideline.

**Up and Down**:

Since pitches are notionally level, "up" and "down" have no literal meaning; nevertheless, they do have strong connotations.  "Up" implies difficulty with a long way to go; whereas, "down" implies ease and approaching a destination.  As a result, toward the middle of the field tends to be represented as "up," and toward the goal line tends to be represented as "down."  "Up" also emphasizes the starting position in the end of the field nearest your reference point, and "down" emphasizes the conclusion of the motion in the end of the field furthest from your reference point.

The reference point is usually established with respect to the player that has possession of the ball or has just had possession of the ball.  A coach could normally say something like: "Watch out!  Their goalie has a strong leg and can kick the ball way down the field."  The meaning is that the opponent's goalie  could kick the ball a long distance across the midfield towards your own goal.

**Other End**:

The "other end" simply emphasizes that it is the end/half of the pitch that is not where the ball starts or is located.  Mostly, this is used to refer to the opponent's end of the pitch.  In referring to the end that includes the goal a player is defending, it would be more usual to refer to "their own end."

Comment: What about this sentence? I usually use "on", how does "down" work? *Every time West Ham attacked **down** the right, they got in behind Swansea's defence."*

Comment: Using "on the right" references a static location on the right side of the field, where something can happen.   Using "down the right" references motion envisioned toward the opponent's goal along the right touchline.  With the former, I imagine the ball already to the right of the goal.  With the latter, I imagine the ball traveling along the length of the field near the right touchline to a position to the right of the goal